# Get Prior Row of Dataframe in For Loop Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

This is what I believe to be a simple logic problem, but I have been working at this for a while and haven't figured it out, so hopefully someone can find the easy solution that I have been missing. I would like to be able to get the prior part of a dataframe using the following code, and have settle for the `(row-1)` solve in the fourth row, but that obviously did not work.

```
for row in players_at_start_of_period.iterrows():
    if(row[1]['PERIOD']):
        continue
    elif(row[1]['PERIOD'] - 2) > (row-1)[1]['PERIOD']:
        sub_map.update = {row[1]['TEAM_ID_1']: split_row(row[1]['TEAM_1_PLAYERS']), row[1]['TEAM_ID_2']: split_row(row[1]['TEAM_2_PLAYERS'])}
    else:
        continue
```

What would I be able to do to access the value that exists one iteration prior to the current value of 'row'? Thanks!

Comment: could u share a sample dataframe with the expected output (no pics pls), and someone should be able to work out your for loop better

Comment: Can you explain what the code is meant to do?

Comment: maybe you need [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to create column with values moved/shifted to previous/next row so you can have both values in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your data is, but `iterrows()` already returns the index, so you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
# read the data from the downloaded CSV file.
df = pd.read_csv('https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/shanebucket/downloads/uk-500.csv')
# set a numeric id for use as an index for examples.
df['index'] = [random.randint(0,1000) for x in range(df.shape[0])]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    previous_name = ''
    if index > 0:
        previous_name = df.loc[index - 1]['first_name']
    print(previous_name, df.loc[index]['first_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we can add a previous_row within the loop that copies the value of the current row just before the iteration exits. That will help in the next iteration to compare the then current row with previous_row.

Let me know if this logic works for you.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to write the code to show what you are talking about. Definitely sounds reasonable. Only thing to consider is what happens in the first iteration, which OP hasn't elaborated on.